# How to force the value of @CreatedBy in JPA Audit

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, auditing

I'm running a spring boot project with JPA (spring-data-jpa version 2.3.0 / hibernate 5.1.0)
How could I force the value of an @Entity's field annotated with @CreatedBy?

The entity:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity(...)
@Getter
@Setter
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class SomeEntity{

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "create_timestamp", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createTimestamp;

    @Column(name = "create_user")
    @CreatedBy
    private String createUser;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "update_timestamp")
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updateTimestamp;

    @Column(name = "update_user")
    @LastModifiedBy
    private String updateUser;
}
```

The configurations:

```
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorProvider")
@Component
public class AuditConfig implements AuditorAware<String> {

    /**
     * The Constant SYSTEM_ACCOUNT.
     */
    public static final String SYSTEM_ACCOUNT = "system";

    /**
     * Gets the current auditor.
     *
     * @return the current auditor
     */
    @Override
    public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {
        String currentUser = getUserFromSecurityContext();
        return Optional.ofNullable(currentUser);
    }
}
```

The problem is that even if I force the value with this code:

```
someEntity.setCreateUser("some other user");
```

the value gets automatically overwritten by JPA.
Is there any other solution apart from creating another field in the table/entity?

Comment: So, you first configure Spring to autopopulate the field for you, and then, you try to populate it yourself?

Comment: Yes, I want the field autopopulated for every insert but when I explicitly set the value, I do not want audit to override my value.

Comment: Well then, that's not possible with `@CreatedBy`. You will simply need to set the value yourself (you can obtain the current authenticated user using `SecurityContextHolder`)

Answer (score 1):

Define your own `CustomCreatedBy` annotation. Use the [Entity lifecycle](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-lifecycle-events) `@PrePersist` where you'll get all the fields that have your custom annotation and if they're null, then you set the value indicating the current user; if not, you leave the existing value.

Comment: I'll try it thank you. do you have any examples of how to do this?